# JTabbedPane+MultiThreading: Open tab in a new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, jtabbedpane

Good day, I want to make in java swing opening tabs in new threads and it would have had the opportunity to run time-consuming tasks to switch between tabs. Tried it, a copy of the tab implement the interface Runnable, but a new thread is not valid (in the debugger it starts hanging about 1 sec, and is killed), as I understand the constructor work out, and all the contents of the swing is placed in its major flows. I read about SwingWorker, but do not quite understand how you can apply it to my problem. If you can, please show an example. Thanks in advance.

P.S.  This is network application, and "load" will serve as a work with the server. That is, in other words, to give the user the ability to switch between tabs until the current tab is a connection.

Comment: see SwingWorker, Runnable#Thread for redirect all long/heavy code to Workers Threads

Comment: All Swing code must execute on a single thread - the EDT. "Open tab in a new thread" must never happen. You can however prepare for it in a different thread via what mKorbel suggests.

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to split the code into the computing and graphics parts. Suppose there is a button in the listener method in which a call to the server. How can I call this method from a listener in another thread (not EDT)?

Comment: You can try to use an Executor as a starting point. That is a thread or thread pool where you can push Runnable object into for execution: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/executors.html

Comment: Thanks, I realized that you need to create new streams are not at the stage of creating tabs, and in the listener, with a call to work with the server. Thank you very much helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to separate the code that does the actual work from code that specifies the GUI. You should search e.g. for the Model-View-Controller-Pattern (MVC).

This way the GUI code can run inside the event-dispatcher-thread (EDT) of Swing / AWT how it is more or less inteded. The code that does the actual work should be as independent from the GUI as possible. Now you can choose to run it in a dedicated thread or whatever fits best into you overall application architecture.

The last part is wire these two (the GUI and the domain logic) together, so that the GUI triggers the worker code or the worker code triggers GUI updates, or whatever satisfies the workflow requirements.